# asp.net mvc 5 entity framework paypal recurring integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, paypal

Greetings i got my application finished, all i need now its to integrate paypal to my application in 2 ways.

- 1)each user pays a monthly fee with paypal.
- 2)i got a page on my    application that they must do a checkout with
  extra fee to see the    content.

I was searching all over the place and i could not find anything for mvc 5 paypal integration with recurring option. Please can you provide me a sample or a good source were to study it? except the paypal documentation. 
Thank you.